# WIFI upload speed C# vs Android Java

Tags: c#, android, stream, wifi

I am working on a WIFI boot loader for an embedded device. It is working fine, but now I want to increase the speed. I have a C# client and an Android client with the device acting as server. The embedded device is rather slow so the clients must sleep between data records while the device writes to program memory. Here is the strange part: Required sleep for the Windows C# client is 300ms while it is 800ms for Android. Any less of a wait causes the server to send an error. This results in an 8 minute operation in C# and 21 minutes in Android. Why is this?

Here is the loop in C#:

```
        for (int line = 0; line < lines.Count; line++) {
            if (lines[line].StartsWith(";")) break;
            byte[] sbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lines[line]);
            gStream.Write(sbytes, 0, sbytes.Length);
            textBoxTerminal.AppendText(lines[line]);
            textBoxTerminal.AppendText("\n");
            Application.DoEvents();
            wait(300);
            if (gStream.DataAvailable) break;
        }
```

Here it is in Android Java:

```
       while((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (data.startsWith(";")) break;
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(data + "\r");     
            lines++;
            mData = lines + " Lines of " + tlines + " sent";
            mHandler.post(mShowData);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            Thread.sleep(800);
            if (inputStream.available() > 0) break;
        }
```

Comment: The wait() in C# uses Stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.

Comment: I thought maybe Android was sending 16 bit data while C# sends 8, but according to Android Developers, "Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits."

Comment: Do you have any control of embedded device code? Because the clients having to wait an arbitrary amount of time seems a horrible design. The embedded device should inform the clients when it's ready.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the device code. I originally had the device reply when ready for more data. The results were the same. C# was much faster than Android. The above code is just for testing, trying to see how fast I can send data.